# Create nodes from CSV in Neo4j

Tags: csv, merge, neo4j, nodes

I have a csv file and I want to make 2 nodes with relation (node country-reported_on->node report_date). I have tried this code but it returns empty nodes with numbers instead of country name.

Here is what my dataset looks like:

```
PEOPLE_POSITIVE_CASES_COUNT;REPORT_DATE;COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME;PEOPLE_DEATH_COUNT;LIFE_EXPECTANCY;GDP;DENSITY_POPULATION;WORKFORCE

0;22.01.2020;Lesotho;0;54.836;875.353432963926;70.5616600790514
134;09.07.2020;Lesotho;1;54.836;875.353432963926;70.5616600790514
79557;02.03.2021;Zambia;1104;64.194;985.132436038869;94.4781600309238
106470;02.03.2021;Kenya;1863;66.991;1878.58070251348;94.4781600309238
```

Here is the code that I used:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///dataset.csv" 
as row WITH row WHERE row.COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME IS NOT NULL
MERGE (c:Country {name: row.COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME,
life_exp: row.LIFE_EXPECTANCY, 
gdp: row.GDP,
density_population: row.DENSITY_POPULATION, 
worforce: row.WORKFORCE } )
MERGE ( d:Report_date { date: row.REPORT_DATE } )
MERGE (c)-[:reported_on {cases_count: row.PEOPLE_POSITIVE_CASES_COUNT,
death_count: row.PEOPLE_DEATH_COUNT}]->(d)
```

**EDIT**
I changed the delimiter to ';' because that is what we had in our dataset however we still get bad results here is how it looks like in neo4j after running this code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///dataset.csv" 
as row FIELDTERMINATOR ';' WITH row WHERE row.COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME IS NOT NULL
MERGE (c:Country {name: row.COUNTRY_SHORT_NAME,
life_exp: row.LIFE_EXPECTANCY, 
gdp: row.GDP,
density_population: row.DENSITY_POPULATION, 
worforce: row.WORKFORCE } )
MERGE ( d:Report_date { date: row.REPORT_DATE } )
MERGE (c)-[:reported_on {cases_count: row.PEOPLE_POSITIVE_CASES_COUNT,
death_count: row.PEOPLE_DEATH_COUNT}]->(d)
```

[image: our result]

Comment: Check the edit as I changed the delimiter

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused with node caption in Neo4j browser, all nodes get assigned an node id by default and nodes must be showing that. You can change it to country name property by clicking on node label. Screen shot for reference.[image: Picture]

Comment: problem is that I get node label country without names like "Kenya" but with numbers like on the screen that I added to the edited post, could you look at that?

Comment: I can see you have created 884 nodes and 90740 properties but still not showing. Can you check the output of `MATCH (c:Country) return c` statement in table format to see if the data is correctly flowing. It might be an UI issue (not sure though)